# OSError: Unable to upload

Tags: python, instagram

I'm havin a rough time trying to fgure this error out. Y try ro run a simple script like the these:

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = "username"
password = "password"

image = "Image.jpg"

description = "This is a test"

with client(username, password) as cli:
    cli.upload(image, description)
```

and i get the following error:

```
[IG] not found cookie/cookie_file >> login as default
Error parsing error response: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Error is >>
    Bad Request

Something went bad.
Please retry or send an issue on https://github.com/b3nab/instapy-cli

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Lucas/Desktop/Python/Proyectos/Insta Automation/Matetemático/Posting Script.py", line 15, in <module>
    cli.upload(imagen, text)
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\instapy_cli\cli.py", line 153, in upload
    raise IOError("Unable to upload.")
OSError: Unable to upload.
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/instagrambot/instapy-cli/issues/104). It seems that the project is dead, maybe is better to fork it and update the instagram API, or just use selenium

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and I solved it by uninstalling  and then re-installing:

```
pip uninstall instapy-cli
pip install instapy-cli
```

Comment: Tried it several times. Didn't worked for me. Did you try uploading a picture with instapy-cli recently?

Comment: I used it more than 6 months ago :) I think doesn't work right now, In fact, I believe that the best solution to do it, it's using selenium :)

Comment: ); i'm afraid that's it, back to the ice age lmao

Comment: Unfortunately, https://www.instagram.com/developer/libraries/ :/

Comment: But, anyway, try to use this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mxyYmBpryK/ , I hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

install these packages should be greater than a specific version
[instabot 0.117.0 requires moviepy>=1.0.1, but you have moviepy 0.2.3.2 which is incompatible.
instabot 0.117.0 requires tqdm>=4.41.1, but you have tqdm 4.11.2 which is incompatible]

try this